# Split string by symbols and put symbols into variables. Java

Tags: java

I have a string variable. It's 4 digits number. I have to split this string into symbols and put every symbol into different variable. 
I haven't found how to do it with variables, only with arrays, but using arrays is not allowed. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using `charAt()` or `codePointAt()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure if i understand the question correctly, but maybe this is a solution?

```
    String strNumber = "1234";
    char one = strNumber.charAt(0);
    char two = strNumber.charAt(1);
    char three = strNumber.charAt(2);
    char four = strNumber.charAt(3);
```